# Passing values to the class associated with a uiview and having draw recognize the values instead of the default class values

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8

See if I can explain this...

- Have a ViewController that has outlets defined for the two UIViews to show the graphs.
- The UIViews have classes attached to them via the "Custom Class" Class property of Identity inspector.
- Each class has an override for "draw" to draw the graph, which on start-up it does.
- Some of the values for the items to be drawn (rectangles) use class variables defined as var with a default value
- In the controller, I set the variables to new values, but when the draw method gets invoked (via outletName.setNeedsDisplay() in the controller), it uses the default values that the class has.

Question. How does one pass new values into the UIView subclass of the UIView so that draw doesn't render the same thing every time? What "simple" thing am I missing?

Other notes

- let currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() is fine first
  time, nil subsequent times
- I set the tag value in the view controller and changed it in the draw
  method and the control had the new value
- print statements in the draw method all print to the console every
  time

Thanks

Maybe a picture helps? "5" is always used

```
ViewController.swift
...@IBOutlet var graphView: UIView!  // linked to GraphController.swift in Identity Inspector
...var graphController = GraphController() // UIView
...buttonClick
......graphContoller.xCoord = 20
......graphController.yCoord = 20
......graphView.setNeedsDisplay()


GraphController.swift
...var xCoord: Int = 5
...var yCoord: Int = 5
...override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
......let rect = CGRect(x: xCoord, y: yCoord, width: 10, height: 10)  <- simplified for example
```

Comment: Your comments say your graphView is "linked to GraphController.swift in Identity Inspector" What does that mean? Is graphView an instance of graphController? How do `var graphView` and `var graphController` relate to each other?

Comment: Basically I clicked on the UIView in the Main.storyboard, then in the Identity Inspector I selected the GraphController as the class.
I also used the Collections Inspector and joined the UIView to the @IBOutlet (graphView). So they both seem to be hooked up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like your `var graphController` is an object that you create that has nothing to do with your view hierarchy. It exists in the abstract, and is never displayed to the screen.

If `graphView` is an outlet linked to an instance of your `GraphController` class that is defined in IB then you should be setting properties on `graphView`, and should get rid of `var graphController` entirely.

### EDIT:

To collect the info from comments into the answer:

You are confused as to how custom view classes work. You don't have "a class associated with a UIView." You create a custom subclass of UIView. Your custom subclass IS a UIView, but it has extra code and/or properties that you add.

You don't set up a view and a controller object that manages that view. (The view controller is the controller object for all of the views that it manages.) You create an instance of your custom view. (For complex objects like table views it might make sense to create a controller object (UITableViewController) that works in tandem with your view object, but that's unusual and you shouldn't do that unless you have a clear understanding of what you are doing and why.)

Here's the steps to create a custom subclass of UIView:

1) Create a new file for the custom class, e.g. MyView.swift:

```
class MyView: UIView {
  //Your custom properties and and methods go here.
}
```

2) In your storyboard, drag a new generic `UIView` object onto the form. Select the identity inspector and change the class of the view to your custom subclass (MyView, in my example). This tells IB (Interface Builder) "When you create a view here, create my custom subclass instead of a generic view." Note that since you defined your custom subclass in step 1, IB should offer to auto-complete the class name for you.

This is like dragging a car object onto the screen, then selecting the car object and switching it's type from "car" to "Prius". A Prius is a car, but it's a specific kind of car with some attributes that other cars don't have.

3) Control-drag from your new custom view (a MyView object in this example) into your view controller's source file and create an outlet. Since you changed the type of the view in step 2, Xcode will set up the outlet using your custom type. Since it's the correct type you can read/write the properties or call the methods on your outlet and the compiler will let you.

Comment: I'm probably missing something simple, but the class is used for the "draw" method. Maybe I'm not hooking them up together correctly. It's odd that the initial load works correctly, but subsequent calls do not. And it's really just that passing values (that are not part of a standard UIView) that don't seem to persist during the call.

Comment: Get rid of `var graphController`. That is a duplicate object that shouldn't exist. Assuming `graphView` is linked to an instance of `GraphController`, change `var graphView: UIView!` to `var graphView: GraphController! and set the properties on `graphView`.

Comment: That was exactly it. I thought the class needed instantiation and would control it.

Comment: That was exactly it. I thought the class needed instantiation and would control it.

**Changing it from:**
`    var graphController = GraphController()
   @IBOutlet var graphView: UIView!

buttonClick
   graphContoller.xCoord = 20
`
**To:**
`   @IBOutlet var graphView: GraphController!

buttonClick
   graphView.xCoord = 20
`

Comment: When you change a view in the IB identity inspector to a different class, the OS creates an instance of that new custom class when the view controller's scene is loaded. Typically to create a custom view you: drag  a generic UIView onto your form, change it's type to your custom type in the identity inspector, and then control-drag into your source to create an outlet of the correct type. If you drag an outlet into the code first it will be of type `UIView`, which you don't want.

Comment: BTW, "GraphConroller" is a bad name for a view object that draws a graph. It implies that it is a controller object - which it's not. `GraphView` would be a much better name.

Comment: Thank you for your help and the thorough explanations. Will be helpful to future people.